# How to simplify $(3\sqrt{x})^3$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Simplify: $(3\sqrt{x})^3$.

Where should I begin?

I have tried to take to whole thing to the 2/3 power but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify? $(3\sqrt{x})^3$ is already pretty simple. Perhaps you are looking for $27x^{3/2}$?

Comment: The tag "calculus" is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$, and then use the fact that $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$, then you have
$$(3\sqrt{x})^3=(3x^{1/2})^3=3^3(x^{1/2})^3$$
By $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, we have ($3^3=27$)
$$\boxed{(3\sqrt{x})^3=27x^{3/2}}$$